# When I upload program to algotester.com it says "Wrong Asnswer" or "Run Time Error" even thought it works fine on my PC

Tags: python, algorithm

So I tried to complete problem on Algotester

This one:

https://algotester.com/en/ArchiveProblem/Display/2

It's a simple one and here's my solution:

'''

```
value = input()

value = value.split()

sum = 0

for i in range(2, len(value)):
    sum += int(value[i]) -1


print(sum)
```

'''

It works correctly (as far I tried)

BUT when I upload it, site says "Wrong answer"

Also with previous versions of this programm I was getting "Run time error"
even thought it worked OK on my pc.

Comment: It is not related to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I do not read Russian, but it looks like the example input given is:

```
4
4           7           47           7
```

So 2 lines of input. Your code only seems to read the first one.